# How can a joinpoint call be stored uniquely?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have an `AspectJ` Aspect that logs and calls a method.  For example,

```
@Aspect
public class MyRetryAspect{

    @Around("@annotation(path.to.an.annotation)")
    public Object logAndRetryServiceCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        log.info("Calling method", joinPoint.getCallSignature.toShortString())
        return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

This logs messages like

```
INFO  c.b.n.e.core.aop.SpringRetryAspect - Calling SomeClass.someMethod(..)
```

When traffic is busy, several services can call `SomeClass.someMethod()` and I'd like to distinguish and store them.  In this way, the `@Aspect` could log more detailed information about the call.  For example, if two threads are calling the aspect back and forth, the logs should denote that these are separate callers.  Something like:

```
INFO  c.b.n.e.core.aop.SpringRetryAspect - Calling SomeClass.someMethod(Object@3233) 
INFO  c.b.n.e.core.aop.SpringRetryAspect - Calling SomeClass.someMethod(Object@3813)
```

This is contrived, but illustrates the idea that the logs can distinguish calls with different arguments.  In practice, I'm logging retry attempts, so if two threads are retrying the same service call, we'd like to distinguish and track them in the logs, eg

```
    INFO  c.b.n.e.core.aop.SpringRetryAspect - Calling SomeClass.someMethod(Object@3233) attempt (1 of 5)

    INFO  c.b.n.e.core.aop.SpringRetryAspect - Calling SomeClass.someMethod(Object@3813) attempt (3 of 5)

   INFO  c.b.n.e.core.aop.SpringRetryAspect - Calling SomeClass.someMethod(Object@3813) attempt (4 of 5)

    INFO  c.b.n.e.core.aop.SpringRetryAspect - Calling SomeClass.someMethod(Object@3233) attempt (2 of 5)
```

So finally, my question is, is there a way to uniquely distinguish one call to a joinpoint from another?  The closest I've come is to try to pull the arguments to `someMethod()` and take the first one and stringfiy it... it's really hacky.  **Is there anything unique that can be extracted from a joinPoint to distinguish one caller from another?**

```
String methodName = String.format("%s[%s]", joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString(), joinPoint.getArgs()[0].toString());
```

Comment: You are matching on an annotation, not on a method signature. How can you be sure that the method actually has an argument? And if you can, do all annotated methods matched by the pointcut have the same type as first argument? Can you please edit the question and show some method signatures which would be matched by the aspect? Unless I know that, I cannot make a good suggestion about how to refactor the aspect to be less hacky. I think I have an idea, but I dislike guessing, I like to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `log4j-api` in your project, you could use class `ThreadContext`.

Then you can store whatever information you want per thread.

For example, before you start calling your methods:

```
ThreadContext.put("thread_id", new AlternativeJdkIdGenerator().generateId().toString());
ThreadContext.put("count_thread_executions", "0");
```

Then in your `Aspect`:

```
@Aspect
public class MyRetryAspect{

    @Around("@annotation(path.to.an.annotation)")
    public Object logAndRetryServiceCall(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        ThreadContext.put("count_thread_executions", ((Integer) (Integer.parseInt(ThreadContext.get("count_thread_executions")) + 1)).toString());
        String count_thread_executions = ThreadContext.get("count_thread_executions");

        // Use count_thread_executions as needed

        log.info("Calling method", joinPoint.getCallSignature.toShortString());
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

And finally don't forget to clear `ThreadContext` after all method executions.

```
ThreadContext.clearAll();
```

I know it is not exactly what you have asked, but hopefully you might find something useful you can use to address your needs.